# Open ZIP/RAR automatically

Tags: windows, zip, rar

do you know some kind of software, or way to script automatic dearchivation on Windows? 
Ideally this thing should work like this:

1. Open file with this script/software
2. It will search files inside by    mask (doc, pdf, jpg...) and if there is <2 of that files - script    will open them, if > - unpack to C:/Temp or whatever
3. If there is    archives inside - go to 1 and perform same thing to them

Any help would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the jolly character("*").
Try telling the script to open a file called *.doc, *pdf or *.jpg.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think jolly character is the only thing I need;)

Comment: Sad i couldn't help, i hope someone else is gonna tell you the answer, good luck with your script.

Comment: I forgot to say that you should try to post the current version of the code! That helps!

Comment: it's called a [wildcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character)